# Multiplication of two variables increase over time

Tags: python, multiplication

This is a question I had as an exercise.

There are two types of bacteria. Say x and y. Every second they multiply while changing their type.

Type x becomes 2 y type and 1 x type (`x -> 2y + x`). Type y becomes 3 x type and 1 y type (`y -> 3x + y`). Other than that, 1 x type and 3 y type are born spontaneously (each second -> `x + 3y`).

The task is to calculate the number of bacteria after a given time `t`.

I wrote a code here:

```
x = 1
y = 1
t = 2

def calcFinalBacteria (x, y, t):
    for i in xrange (t):
        tempX = x + y * 3 # contribution by x bacteria (1) and y bacteria (3)
        tempY = x * 2 + y # contribution by x bacteria (2) and y bacteria (1)

        x += tempX + 1 - x # spontaneous addition of 1 x bacteria
        y += tempY + 3 - y # spontaneous addition of 3 y bacteria
    print x, y

calcFinalBacteria (x, y)
```

The time complexity of my code is O(t) here. But is there any way for improvement? For small inputs it is okay. But when I push t up to 10^18 and increase x, y up to 1000, it takes much time to find out

Comment: This is a mathematical problem. Is there a closed formula that can compute this series `nth` element in constant time? I would take it to math.stackexchange.com

Comment: Also, the `//` syntax for comments is not valid `python`. That code doesn't run. It's hard to believe this is not example code from a homework assignment

Comment: Maybe. But the main reason I posted this question here is to find whether there is a chance to improve my code. I searched for this type of multiplicative questions online, but none of them had an acceptable algorithm.

Comment: sorry. my bad. I added the comments in editing page after I copy pasted my code. Thought comments could provide more information.

Comment: This is a lot like some of the exercises in Chapter 1 of SICP.  It might be amenable to some kind of divide and conquer approach if you can find a clever recurrence relation.

Comment: It's not something you solve in code. Get pen and paper and find a formula to compute it directly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So if I'm understanding this right, `x' = x+3y+1` and `y' = 2x+y+3`.  Suppose your initial population is ten x and seven y, and you want to evolve it by one step.  This can be modeled with the following matrix multiplication:

```
|1 3 1|   |10|
|3 1 3| x | 7|
|0 0 1|   | 1|
```

So to find the answer, you need to repeat the matrix multiplication `t` times.

Although, the way you've written the code, each x turns into 2y and 0 x, not 2y and one x.

Comment: Which then be accelerated to `O(log T)` by noting that `A*A*A*A = (A^2)*(A^2)`.

Comment: Absolutely beauty to see linear algebra come into the scene.

Answer (score 1):

One small improvement.

You were adding the value to itself and the subtracting it's original value.

```
x = 1
y = 1
t = 2

def calcFinalBacteria (x, y, t):
    for i in xrange (t):
        tempX = x + y * 3 # contribution by x bacteria (1) and y bacteria (3)
        tempY = x * 2 + y # contribution by x bacteria (2) and y bacteria (1)

        x = tempX + 1 # spontaneous addition of 1 x bacteria
        y = tempY + 3 # spontaneous addition of 3 y bacteria
    print x, y

calcFinalBacteria (x, y)
```